# Custom font not displaying in SVG pattern used as background-image

Tags: html, css, firefox, svg, background-image

I'm working with **an SVG pattern that uses a custom font**, so as to use that **pattern as a background image** on an HTML page.

Everything renders fine in Chrome and Safari but it starts to get funny in Firefox:

- Firefox renders the SVG along with the custom font text just fine when I open the SVG file itself (so far so good!);
- However, Firefox does **NOT** render the custom font anymore when that same SVG file is used as the background to an HTML element (!)

I've spent hours trying to isolate the issue and a fresh pair of eyes would be welcome.

Here's what I've got in short:

**CSS:**

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower);

body {
    background: url(pattern-google.svg);
}
```

**SVG file:**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" height="200" width="200">
    <style type="text/css">@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower);</style>
    <defs>
        <!-- Geometry -->
        <g>
            <rect id="square" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" />
        </g>

        <!-- Patterns with Text -->
        <pattern id="pattern" x="0" y="0" width="40" height="40" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" text-anchor="middle" font-size="20" font-family="Indie Flower, sans-serif" style="font-family: Indie Flower, sans-serif;">
            <rect x="00" y="00" width="40" height="40" fill="transparent" />
            <text x="00" y="00" fill="#777">S</text>
            <text x="40" y="00" fill="#777">S</text>
            <text x="20" y="20" fill="#777">S</text>
            <text x="00" y="40" fill="#777">S</text>
            <text x="40" y="40" fill="#777">S</text>
        </pattern>
    </defs>

    <!-- Graphics -->
    <use xlink:href="#square" transform="translate(0, 0)" fill="url(#pattern)"/>
</svg>
```

The HTML itself does not really matter but I've linked it below.
I did not produce a jsfiddle in the end because I could not host the SVG file there.

(Outside of the demo, the real-world application here is that I want to use a custom font to display phonetic symbols. (As background image, to help people learn them.) Doing so in SVG saves me the hassle to export to bitmap anytime I make a change in design.)

Comment: As of Firefox 46.0.1 (or maybe earlier), the issue is gone.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are using SVG in an image context. I.e. either via the html `<img>` tag, the SVG `<image>` tag or in your case as a background image.

In Firefox (and likely in other UAs at some point) images must consist of a single file only. Any data external to the image file (pattern-google.svg) is ignored. If you display the SVG directly then external data is loaded/used.

So what can you do...

Load the data as a [data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme). I.e. base64 encode http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower **but read the final paragraph before you do this** and then stick that data directly in the svg file itself.

So the import would look like this...

```
@import url('data:text/css;base64,whatever the base 64 encoded data looks like...')
```

Do be careful though because http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower itself has external data so that data itself must itself be encoded as a data URI. I.e. you must go all the way down the rabbit hole. And change that file as I've sketched out below.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Indie Flower';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Indie Flower'), local('IndieFlower'), url(**convert this file to a data URI too before you convert the whole file to a data URI**) format('woff');
}
```

Once you've done that you can then encode the whole file as a data URI and @import it.

So, to reiterate step by step...

1. Convert http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/indieflower/v5/10JVD_humAd5zP2yrFqw6nhCUOGz7vYGh680lGh-uXM.woff to a data URI
2. Replace http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower with a version that has the data URI from step 1
3. Convert the file in step 2 to a data URI
4. @import the data URI from step 3

There are plenty of sites online that will create data URIs.